# Rspec + Capybara + requests: have_selector not returning anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec2

I have the following request rspec test:

```
describe "CRUD" do
  it "should list users" do
    10.times do
      FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    end

    visit users_path
    page.should have_selector('table tr', :count => 10)
  end
end
```

The problem is that it always gives this error:

```
1) Users CRUD should list users
    Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('table tr', :count => 10)
    expected css "table tr" to return something
```

Any ideas of why this is happening? It looks very similar to the test in rspec manual.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running `save_page` right before the `have_selector` test and then seeing what Capybara sees?

Comment: your test is correct, Per_se, do you have a github we might take a look at your source?

Comment: @MrDanA Just did it and yes, there is a table. https://gist.github.com/2645062

Comment: expected to return sometimes just means that the thing you are looking for is not there. Can you post your view code?

Comment: @TheIrishGuy It's not on github, but which file/source would you need exactly? I can post it as a gist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the capybara docs, supplying count checks for that exact number. You're checking for 10 rows, but you have 12.

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_selector%3F-instance_method

Comment: Wow, that was it. I thought it was saying that "table tr" was not returning *anything* as i had this problem before. I changed it to minimum or the exact count and it worked correctly. Thank you.